# I want SharePoint REST API which returns particular document level permission User Name

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

We need to view document item level permission, with User Names. We need REST API call to get item level permission. Also just for particular item which permission contains.

Till now I have used following code.

```
var itemurl =  _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +  "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Sustaining')/Items(78)/RoleAssignments";
$.ajax({
         url: itemurl,
         method: "GET",
         async: false,
         headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
         success: function (data) 
         {
           console.log(data);
              if (data!=null ) {
                  console.log(data);
              }        
         },
        error: function (error) {
            //alert("Error: "+ JSON.stringify(error));
       }
    });
```

not working for me

Comment: Hi Prashant, can you please add some brief description in the question.

Comment: We need to view document item level permission, with User Names. We need REST API call to get item level permission. We need to just get for particular item which permission contains.

Answer (score 1):

I published a quick post on this at [Display the SharePoint list item permissions using REST API](http://www.thesharepointguide.com/display-sharepoint-list-item-permissions-using-rest-api/)

Let me know if it works for you.